# DNNClassifier does not show average loss in Tensorboard when using SUM_OVER_BATCH_SIZE

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I'm feeding my `tf.estimator.DNNClassifier` data in batches and I want to visualize the loss as the model is trained. When I use the default `SUM` loss reduction I see the average loss in a chart in Tensorboard. If I use the `SUM_OVER_BATCH_SIZE` the loss chart vanishes. Is there a way to see the loss over the training?

What I have is as follows:

```
import tensorflow as tf

features = ... # all of type tf.feature_column.numeric_column(...)
weight_col = ... # of type tf.feature_column.numeric_column(key=...)

def train_input_fn():
    ...

def eval_input_fn():
    ...

config = tf.estimator.RunConfig(model_dir=job_dir).replace(save_summary_steps=5)

estimator = tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(
    feature_columns=features,
    hidden_units=[50, 100, 50],
    weight_column=weight_col,
    n_classes=2,
    activation_fn=tf.nn.relu,
    optimizer=tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.005),
    loss_reduction=tf.losses.Reduction.SUM_OVER_BATCH_SIZE,
    dropout=0.001,
    config=config)

estimator.train(input_fn=train_input_fn, max_steps=10000)
eval = estimator.evaluate(input_fn=eval_input_fn)
```

I'm on TensorFlow 1.9.0.

Comment: Could you please show your current code?

Comment: @Sharky I updated the question